# How can I run a batch file in Vim's console?

Tags: command-line, gvim, external-command, microsoft-windows

I want to use Vim as a simple c++ editor in windows (I have no experience with Linux). Nothing fancy, just want to get things started.

To compile a .cpp file from CMD I have to run a batch file in the CMD and then I can compile and run the program, i.e `g++ -o program program.cpp`.

I want to do this directly from Vim, like a custom command that does both runs the specific batch file and the run command.

I am completely beginner in Vim and currently have no idea what to do next. Thanks for helping me.

Edit :

All i want is a way to open **Windows CMD** then **Run my batch file** and then **run  `g++ -o program program.cpp`**. How can i do that with single command in Vim.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need to run that batch file? To set `PATH` to include `g++` and all? If so, you should consider opening a console, running that script from the console and eventually launching Vim from that same console. Or you could make sure the *"environment variables"* set in that script are defined to be always set on your windows system.

Then, depending on what provides you gcc, it could be very simple to compile single file programs from vim. Typing `:make %<` is enough with a correctly configured programming environment. On Windows, this means installing g++ through cygwin distribution. Mingw is very badly configured. With this one, you'll have to set `:set makeprg=g++\ -o\ $*\ $*.cpp` (typed from memory -- I stay away from mingw and thus, I never need to do this) -- or if you really want to run vim from the window explorer: `:let &makeprg = 'c:/path/to/that/script.bat && g++ -o $* $*.cpp'`. Or you can define a Makefile as others have explained you.

More details about what is possible with a correctly configure programming environment on the big sister/brother site: https://stackoverflow.com/a/35702919/15934

Answer (score 0):

`:!cmd` runs `cmd` as if you were running it from the terminal!

Since you want to build code, you can think of writing a `Makefile` and using that. As above, you can run `:!make` to call `make`. vim has a `:make` command that actually calls `make` for you, so you might find it easier to use (as a bonus, `:mak` does the same and is shorter).

Comment: I want a custom command to do both run that batch file and run the program. How can i achieve that ?

Comment: I think you can use `&&` in Windows @A---B ? i.e. `:!program1 && program2`? Or perhaps a `;`? `:!program1; program2`?

Comment: @Carpetsmoker so you mean `:!cmd my batch file && g++ -o p p.cpp` right ?

Comment: @A---B I don't think you don't need the `cmd`; Vim adds that for you. Just `:!file` will do.

Comment: @Carpetsmoker So, `:!file my batch file location && g++ -o p p.cpp` right ?

Comment: @A---B I don't have a Windows machine to test, but why don't you try it and muck about a bit? That's a great way to learn ;-) Also remember that Vim comes with some pretty good documentation, so be sure to read [`:help :!`](http://vimhelp.appspot.com/various.txt.html#%3a%21).

Comment: @Carpetsmoker it says `!file` is not a command, :(. i already tried documentation but can't find what i need

Comment: Just create a new (e.g. `run`) target in your `makefile`, that depends on the build target, and then issue `:make run` from Vim afterwards.

Comment: @A--B, `cmd` in my example is the actual command you want to execute! So your build example would be `:!g++ -p p p.cpp`. It's seriously painful to type all that every time, so you should seriously look into writing a `Makefile`. Even without a `Makefile`, you can run a shell script and run that, which can take care of building and running.

Comment: P.S. If you have the option, give Linux a try. You may be surprised at how easy it is for programmers, and how convenient using the terminal is.